# http_user_agent not showing android version

Tags: php, android, user-agent

I am using `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` to get browser and OS details of the device.When I am used in android mobile,it is not showing the version of android os.It shows like this

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Android; Mobile; rv:19.0) Gecko/19.0 Firefox/19.0
```

How can I get the android version.Please help me..

Comment: Have you tried with a few devices? I think your device does not pass the Android version with the user agent string.

Comment: if user agent header looks like this, simply, you can't

Comment: Yes,Some devices are not not showing the version as told by @Dediqated.

Answer (score 0):

If the client doesn't identify itself as Android in HTTP_USER_AGENT there isn't much you can do server-side.
You might try to see if you can detect further info using Javascript, but then you'd have to pass the information to PHP, maybe using a cookie or redirecting the user to an appropriate URL via Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your help @LucaTNT..Can you tell me which javascript funtion I can use...?

Comment: You can use navigator.userAgent to get the user agent, though I'm afraid it'll return the same thing you already get in PHP